# Match multiple ip addresses to one endpoint

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, ipv6

My situation is the following:

*(I don't know if this is relevant but all the following is/should be done with c on a linux machine.)*

I am doing peer discovery in my local network using IPv4 broadcast packets and IPv6 multicast packets. Peers who receive a broadcast/multicast packet from another peer send back a response signaling that they are online.

Because I am broadcasting on all interfaces and and using both IPv4 and IPv6 I get at least two responses from one endpoint (one IPv4 and one IPv6). If another endpoint is reachable through multiple interfaces (wifi + ethernet e.g) I might get even more responses from a single endpoint.

[image: Peer 2 gets a response via 3 Paths]

In this example Peer 2 gets three responses from Peer 1 after broadcasting an IPv4 packet on his WiFi and Ethernet cards and sending a IPv6 multicast packet with his WiFi card. Peer 2 has now 3 Responses from the same host with different IPs.

**My question is if there is any way to match all those responses to a single endpoint without embedding some kind of id in the response packets?**

If this is not possible my next question would be how to pick a good identification. The id does not have to be unique per host but only per host per session. A simple random number could create a collision between two peers which is a case I don't want to handle if I don't have to. The id should also be short to not bloat the packet too much.

I appreciate any comments/answers.

Comment: What if you just use the MAC address of the ethernet interface as the id? That will be unique per host. It's only 6 bytes, which doesn't seem "bloated" unless you're working with embedded devices with memory measured in kilobytes.

Comment: I already thought about that. I think that this won't be unique per host but per network card. So in the given example I could match both WiFi packets but not all three. Also, to my knowledge, getting the ethernet header requires raw sockets which I can't use because this has to work without special priviliges.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I am not suggesting that you try to extract the MAC address from the header of incoming packets.  I am suggesting that *on the sending client* you embed the MAC address in your message as the client id.

Comment: That works around the privilege problem but not the problem that different network cards have different MAC addresses right?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what problem you're describing.  If you decide that "the MAC address of eth0" (or "the MAC address of the lowest numbered interface") will be your client id, it doesn't matter how many interfaces the client has or what interface was used to send the message.  All messages emitted by the client will have the same id, and it will be unique to that client.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for the clarification. This is a reasonably short unique identification. The original question was if it is possible to identify the host of all three packets **without** embedding the id. Do you have any idea on that?

Comment: There is no way to correlate multiple messages from different addresses to the same source host without embedding some sort of identification into the packets (or performing some sort of authentication exchange at the beginning of a TCP session, in which case you wouldn't need to include the identifier in every packet as long as it was part of an established connection).

Comment: Alright thank you. If you want you can post this as an answer so I can mark it as answered ;)

Comment: Using broadcast on IPv4 is a rookie move that can get your application banned. Broadcast interrupts _every_ host on the LAN. You can also use multicast on IPv4 to only interrupt the hosts interested in your traffic. Because of heightened security, many companies are closely testing software, ad behavior such as broadcast or multicast to every host on a LAN is suspect, and it can get your application rejected outright.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is if there is any way to match all those responses to a single endpoint without embedding some kind of id in the response packets?

There is no way to correlate multiple messages from different addresses to the same source host without embedding some sort of identification into the packets (or performing some sort of authentication exchange at the beginning of a TCP session, in which case you wouldn't need to include the identifier in every packet as long as it was part of an established connection).

> If this is not possible my next question would be how to pick a good identification. The id does not have to be unique per host but only per host per session.

Use the MAC address of a network interface as the client identifier.  This will give you a six-byte client identifier which will be unique per host.  Use a rule like "the MAC address of `eth0`" or "the MAC address of the lowest numbered interface" to consistently select the value.

It's probably worth noting that while the MAC address may not be *guaranteed* to be unique, it is *effectively* guaranteed: as long as (a) all of your clients share at least one common network and (b) you use the MAC address of the interface on that network, then either it will be unique or you will have bigger problems to deal with, because one or more of your clients will be unable to participate on the network.